# How to select appended element in UL list

Tags: jquery

I want to add a `<li>` to my `<ul>` list below, above the `.last-child`:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>item 1<li>
    <li>item 2<li>
    <li>item 3<li>
    <li class="last-child"><li>
</ul>
```

I am using the following jQuery code to do so:

```
var result = '<li>item 4</li>';
$("#list li.last-child").before(result);
```

That all works fine. However, I want to select the newly added row... Normally I guess I could use the following code to select the last `<li>`:

```
var $newrow = $('#list').find('li:last');
```

But in this case I want to select the second last `<li>`, how do I select the second last `<li>` which is the one I just inserted?

Am I making sense?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = $('<li>item 4</li>');
$('#list li:last-child').before( result );

// result reference is saved, so keep on using result.

// However you could have used .prev() to anchor to the previous element.
```